# What is the best way to parser XML for intermittent events?

Tags: xml, groovy

Currently, I receive small byte packets from a different server.  They make up an XML document.

So far what I have done is convert the bytes and add it into a String, which serves as a buffer.  I regex to find any XML messages and subtract from the String.  Then I convert them into nodes using an XmlParser and process them.

I am wondering if there is an easier way to do this--I have heard of a streaming XML parser, but when I look it up myself, they don't seem to provide this kind of functionality.

Comment: It would seem that a pushing XML parser, like SAX, would do exactly what you want.

Comment: Is this in Java or Groovy?

Comment: This is Groovy-I'll remove the Java tag.